# Web scraping using Selenium and BeautifulSoup does not update extracted code after scrolling

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape reviews of some games on Steam. Only 10 reviews are available on the review page unless you scroll to the bottom of the page, and more reviews will be loaded.
I use selenium to scroll, but the BeautifulSoup object, which is expected to contain 20 reviews, still only has 10.
Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:\Download\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://steamcommunity.com/app/466560/reviews/?browsefilter=toprated&snr=1_5_100010_')
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I did it and I checked the len(soup.text) and keep increasing every time I scrolled down and get the new soup

Comment: @IslamTaha I don't quite understand. What do you mean by 'every time I scrolled down'?

Comment: driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

Comment: It actually got updated. Really weird cuz when I tried to print soup 30 mins ago it stayed the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until element ID `action_wait` not visible and find text if no more review or simply set max review that you want.

In this example the result limited to 100, you can increase it but if you don't want to wait longer just `Ctrl + C` and the data will be processed to beautifulsoup.

```
driver.get('https://.....')
maxResult = 100
currentResults = 0
pageSource = ''

try:
    print('press "Ctrl + C" to stop loop and process using beautfulsoup.')
    while currentResults < maxResult:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "action_wait")))
        currentResults = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.apphub_Card.modalContentLink.interactable'))
        print('currentResults: %s' % currentResults)
        pageSource = driver.page_source
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Cancelled by user"
except: pass

soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')

reviews = soup.select('.apphub_Card.modalContentLink.interactable')

print('reviews count by BeautifulSoup: %s' % len(reviews))
```

Answer (score 1):

The page updates using jquery with batches of 10 records per scroll. It offsets each time to get next set. There is text visible when the list is exhausted you can use this to scroll until the end. If you want to stop at any particular point have the loop exit condition be the desired number of reviews given by `len(d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.reviewInfo'))`

```
from selenium import webdriver

d  = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/app/466560/reviews/?browsefilter=toprated&snr=1_5_100010_'
d.get(url)

while d.find_element_by_css_selector('.apphub_NoMoreContentText1').text != 'No more content. So sad.':
    d.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    try: 
        d.find_element_by_id('GetMoreContentBtn').click()
    except:
        pass
print(len(d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.reviewInfo')))  #6135
```